# How Firebase auth Really distinguish between real user or hacker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, security

### Scenario

#### Fire store model

```
uid1
  name :john
uid2
  name : alex
```

#### Frontend

(react-firebase)

Login with credentials

Requesting Db to give the name of the user with uid = uid1

and User getting uid from `firebase.auth.currentUser.uid` ( something like this )

#### Backend

(node js admin sdk for firebase )

checking If uid is valid or not If valid give him the name = john

## Hacker Scenario

**Hacker got the uid some how**

Now Requesting backend to give me data and backend is serving it as it is valid uid

Now user got alerted and change the password but acc. to firebase uid does not change so hacker still has the uid and  can get the personal info without any Hassell

## Help me !

What is the best practice and how to deal with this scenario can any body help me with it ?????

Comment: Please help someone